# How to get over Keyboard-interactive authentication prompt in batch file for transferring files to SFTP server

Tags: sftp, putty

[image: error]

I am trying to transfer some text files on SFTP Server using Putty command line option.

I have a batch file with the following commands:

```
(
echo cd /inbox
echo mput c:\temp\*.txt
echo bye
echo cd c:\temp\
echo del c:\temp\*.txt
) |echo open <username@ip> <port no> -pw password
```

However, when I execute the batch file I get stuck at "Keyboard interactive prompt from Server"

Appreciate any suggestions on how to get over this point to avoid manual intervention while executing this batch file?

Comment: The alleged batch file in your question is nonsense and does not match the code in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the reason i was experiencing this issue. I my password i had a special character ^ (power symbol), and while i had passed correct password in batch file it was somehow skipping only that ^ character in password. To overcome this I tried to provide password in batch within double quotes "password" and then my issue was resolved.

Just sharing my experience.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRLw0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar problem when trying to use putty to make an ssh connection, exactly the same warning message "Keyboard interactive prompt from Server". I could write the username but it never accepted the password, also my external ip address did not even made connection, local ip server address worked but password always failed, I was prepared to make a restore from backup, but since I had physical contact with the server, I just plugged an USB Keyboard and "voilá" all problems ended. Maybe Kernel had not loaded the keyboard ascii software or something and somehow it is also needed on remote ssh connection.